# Since updating to business_time gem version 0.9.2 dates miscalculating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jenkins, time, rubygems

I've got a daily smoke test running every morning in multiple environments via Jenkins from around 6 - 8 AM.

Everything was running smoothly until I updated `business_time` gem to version 0.9.2 from 0.9.1. Now the date calculation I have `0.business_days.from_now` calculates to *yesterday's date*.

This only happening in the morning runs. When running in the late morning, after, etc, the date properly calculates to *today's date*

Anyone else experiencing issues with this? I'm assuming I need to change something in `config.yml` for business hours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem was already fixed in `develop`, unless it’s released, I would suggest you to either use `github: "bokmann/business_time", branch: :develop` or to downgrade to `0.9.1`. Here is a diff [`develop`..`v0.9.2`](https://github.com/bokmann/business_time/compare/v0.9.2...develop).

Note:

```
 def after(time = Time.current)
   - positive_days? ? calculate_after(time, @days) : ...
   + non_negative_days? ? calculate_after(time, @days) : ...
 end
```

`v0.9.2` erroneously introduced step back on zero adjustment.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ open source brings an ability to check the code, which is always faster, easier and cleaner, than asking on SO :)